# Finding uniform set of Rows returned by rank in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, row, rank, row-number, analytical

I have a table in Postgresql

for which I performed analytical function and grouped as  lastest records based on column_3

table 1:

[image: ![enter image description here]

now as per the resulset org:2  have latest date(29-07-2023) so I should return all records of org:2  of rank 1,2,3

later ,in case if new value is added for  column_3   for org:1  with date greater than lastest date of org:2(29-07-2023) then all records with ranks 1,2,3 based on org:1 should be returned

Query used:

```
    select column_1,column_2,column_3,column_4 ,dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY (column_3) ORDER BY column_4 desc) rn
from table_1;
```